# DirectX 2D img on screen

Tags: c++, directx

http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/directx-and-xna/directdraw-programming-tutorial-r608

Hi, I just copyed this code to Empty project in visual studio 2010 to source file named main.cpp. When I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _DirectDrawCreate@12 referenced in function "bool __cdecl DirectDrawInit(struct HWND__ *)" (?DirectDrawInit@@YA_NPAUHWND__@@@Z)   C:\Users\Ondra\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Game\Game\main.obj Game
```

and this error:

```
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Ondra\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Game\Debug\Game.exe    1   1   Game
```

What is wrong? :(

Comment: Need more info. Looks like you are missing includes or more likely you have not specified the correct libraries. Also, I think this is way too complicated for new-ish.

Comment: Ty for reply. So what should I do? What info exactly?

Comment: Firstly, what do you think DirectDraw does?

Comment: My tutorial said that it manipulates with bitmaps directly in video memory

Comment: And I thought that I can use it to draw bitmap on screen

Comment: You are looking for windows GDI. The very first thing, can you write any code in C++ and understand it? I think you need to learn a bit more. Start with the console.

Comment: Last comment, Win32 C++: http://www.functionx.com/win32/ and http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/

Comment: I just wanna something what makes me able to draw image on screen with c++ so I can make my school task, I already created classes and game system and now I just need to display it. So can you give me some advice how to do it? I don't want to understand it in this moment, just wanna something like XNA in C# where is something like spriteBatch.Draw(image, position, color..)

Comment: See SpriteBatch in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929). It's a C++ implementation of XNA Game Studio's C# SpriteBatch for Direct3D 11.

Comment: The wrong thing is that you are using code from 15 years old article: `DirectDraw Programming Tutorial. Published Aug 06 1999 09:46 PM`. And you don't even bothering reading explanations: `"you need to create an import library from DDRAW.DLL with the IMPLIB.EXE utility..."`. Though, I doubt it would work. DirectDraw was deprecated long ago. If you still want to try here are the docs: [DirectDraw - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg426115%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Otherwise, check Chuck Walbourn's comment.